# uitableviewcell swipe gesture left and right

Tags: ios, uitableview, swipe

https://maniacdev.com/2014/08/ios-tutorial-and-code-example-on-creating-tinder-style-swipe-to-choose-views

this link help to my uitableviewcell swipe left to right and right to left background image is show but my problem is not show in background image ,
show in image swipe left to right  tableviewcell so plz help , 
then check this link uiview swipe in left and right overlay image is show to how to create in uitableviewcell swipe left and right overlay image show in cell.